# Gmail api credential files

Tags: gmail-api

I have integrated my .net application to send e-mails from Gmail, I have 5 mail accounts that now send e-mails.
For every e-mail account I have created the credential file, when the application is running the first time I most enter the credentials from the e-mail to authenticate itself.

For sending a mail from Gmail you must passed trough the correct json file, that's is created for the specific mail-account.

This has worked for the last 5 months, but now it is not possible to send any e-mails.

Now the credential files are mixed-up, when the mail is automatically send i recieve and 403 that i'm not authenticated.  But the email that is given is one of the others mail accounts.

I don't recieve the consist popup to authenticate it self anymore.

Have anyone has the same issue?

regards

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.   Are you using google workspace accounts for this or standard gmail accounts?   What type of application do you have web, installed?  Is the project in google developer console in production or test?   How are you storing the credentials you speak of.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.